# Movie downloaded from iTunes store on iPad, not available on Mac

Tags: itunes, ipad, itunes-match, itunes-store

I downloaded the movie "Hugo" from the iTunes store during Apple's "12 days of gifts", on my iPad. I have iTunes match for my music (and presumably also for movies), however when I go to see the list of movies on iTunes on my mac, it doesn't show "Hugo." Why would this be the case? Normally when I download something on my iPad (apps, music) I can also get them on my computer. Both my mac & iPad are signed in to the same iTunes account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can find a Purchased section in iTunes Store, under that section, you can select to view your movies.

Also, you can log out and log back into iTunes Store (not authorize/deauthorize, log in and out). You do have to rematch iTunes Match after signing out, but it is just a single one-pass scan which will be fast.

If it not there, you may have to contact iTunes support.

Answer (score 2):

I recently saw this bug too. Had purchased something on my iOS device, it wouldn't sync over, and the movie wasn't showing up in my purchased list in iTunes Store.

I went to the menu bar and choose the option to Check for Available Downloads. This pulled the movie fresh from iTunes and down into my mac iTunes library. Hope this helps!